# Word for "waiting longingly/expectantly"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> Many people [...] for the end of the days.

I thought of the word *anticipate*. But I think it sounds a bit like an understatement.

Comment: How about " Crave" word?? i.e Many people crave for the end of the days.

Comment: Many people _long_ for the end of days?

Comment: Do you mean *the end of the day* (like the end of the workday) or *the end of days* (like the end of the world)? There are people waiting for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Many people **yearn/long/pine/pant** for the end of the days. ("pine/pant" are not so common)
>
> Many people **await** the end of the days. ("await" is not very strong but does convey expectation)

Answer (score 0):

Many people are [longing](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/longing) for the end of the days.

Longing - strong, persistent desire or craving, esp. for something unattainable or distant.

Many people are [looking forward](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/look+forward+to) to the end of the days.

Looking forward- to anticipate something with pleasure

Comment: You cannot use "look forward for". It has to be "look forward to".